# what does &rest mean in elisp?

Tags: emacs, lisp, elisp

What does the `&rest` mean in this: `(append &rest sequences)`

I have finished the book "elisp_intro"，but I didn't find the answer. I will be very grateful if you can help me.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

It indicates that the following argument is the "rest" argument. In the case of your example, `sequences` is the rest argument.

Unlike a normal argument, the rest argument will consume the "rest" of any parameters provided by the user. It is a way of making a function that accepts a variable number of arguments. Inside the function body, the argument will be a list containing all of the extra parameters.

So if you had a function that looked like `(add &rest numbers)`, then you could call it like `(add 1 2 3 4 5)`, and within the function the `numbers` argument would have the value `(1 2 3 4 5)`.

Or for example, `((lambda (a &rest r) r) 1 2 3) ;=> (2 3)`

Comment: It's worth noting that the `apply` function works nicely in conjunction with the `&rest` feature, as `apply` requires its final argument to be an argument list. So if you need to accept a variable number of arguments in order to pass them into another function, these two features make that convenient to do.

Answer (score 11):

Any arguments following the &rest symbol in a function definition will be collected into a single list object. So in the case of (append &rest sequences), if you call the function:

```
(append 1)
```

the variable sequences will be the list (1) in the body of the function. If you call it as

```
(append 1 2 3)
```

the variable sequences will be the list (1 2 3) in the body of the function. This is explained in the Elisp Reference manual, in the [argument list node](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Argument-List.html#Argument-List).

```
(info "(elisp)Argument List")
```

Answer (score 3):

elisp/Common Lisp `&rest` is analogous to the `*args` parameter in Python

If you put this in your Common Lisp repl and call foo with varying numbers of arguments, you will see what's up quite quickly.

```
(defun foo (a b &rest trailing) 
  (format t "~a :: ~a :: ~a~%" a b trailing))
```